# How to export Point-shape coordinates to csv (X,Y)?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, export, csv

I am trying to export point coordinates from a shapefile to a CSV file. I managed to create this:

[image]

but I need the output to look like this:

[image]

I tried different options with save as... and with the MMQgis-plugin, None of them worked.

Does anyone know how to export the file to make it look like the example I gave?

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried searching this site for answers — this question is likely a duplicate? Also, you have different numbers in the point coordinates, so please explain what you expect to happen.

Comment: I searched this site for answers, but im not a native Speaker, so if there's a duplicate i could not find it with the wording i used. the different numbers in the point coordinates are a given for processing.

Answer (score 6):

In the save as dialog you will see a drop down labelled geometry which let's you choose x, y instead of wkt.

[image]

Comment: I think i never saw that option :/ This is even simpler.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create 2 columns (decimal number type) X and Y and fill them with **$x** and **$y** with the [Field calculator](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html).
If you need to go fast, use the **Export/add geometry column** tool in Processing panel. It will add Xcoord and Ycoord columns to your attribute table. This tool can be quite useful as you can choose to calculate the coordinates in the layer coordinates system or the project coordinate system for example.

[image: tool add geom]

If you need to reorder your fields for the final output, use the **Refactor Tool** and save as... directly as a csv file :

[image: tool refactor]